# groupby a dataframe column and merge rows into columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame:

> ```
> ┌────────┬──────────┬─────────┐
> │ s_test │ s_method │ s_error │
> ├────────┼──────────┼─────────┤
> │ n32    │ A        │    0.12 │
> │ n32    │ B        │    0.54 │
> │ n32    │ A        │    0.48 │
> │ n32    │ B        │    0.25 │
> │ n33    │ A        │    0.52 │
> │ n33    │ B        │    0.42 │
> │ n33    │ A        │    0.13 │
> │ n33    │ B        │    0.18 │
> └────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
> ```

```
structure(list(s_test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("n32", "n33"), class = "factor"), s_method = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    s_error = c(0.12, 0.54, 0.48, 0.25, 0.52, 0.42, 0.13, 0.18
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I would like to group by `s_test` and have additional columns like `mean_error_A` and `mean_error_B`.

So far I tried:

```
test_sum <- group_by(sdata, s_test) %>%
  summarise(
    mean = mean(s_error, na.rm = TRUE),
  )
```

and I get:

> ```
> ┌────────┬────────┐
> │ s_test │  mean  │
> ├────────┼────────┤
> │ n32    │ 0.3475 │
> │ n33    │ 0.3125 │
> └────────┴────────┘
> ```

I want to get this:

> ```
> ┌────────┬────────┬────────┐
> │ s_test │ mean_A │ mean_B │
> ├────────┼────────┼────────┤
> │ n32    │ 0.3000 │ 0.3950 │
> │ n33    │ 0.3250 │ 0.3000 │
> └────────┴────────┴────────┘
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to group by 's_test' and 's_method' and then do a `spread` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
sdata %>%
     group_by(s_test, s_method = str_c('mean_', s_method)) %>%
     summarise(mean = mean(s_error)) %>%
     spread(s_method, mean)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   s_test [2]
#  s_test mean_A mean_B
#  <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 n32     0.3    0.395
#2 n33     0.325  0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
reshape2::dcast(data = d,
                formula = s_test ~ s_method,
                value.var = "s_error",
                fun.aggregate = mean)
#  s_test     A     B
#1    n32 0.300 0.395
#2    n33 0.325 0.300
```